# Yii CListView's friendly url using history.js

Tags: yii

I'm trying to make friendly urls using ClistView with history.js enabled.

right now my urls look like this

```
localhost/ModuleName/controllerName/PageName/index/?PageName_sort=price.desc&PageName_page=3
```

I'm trying to make it look nicer (*?PageName_sort=price.desc&PageName_page=3*) to something like this or **something similar**

```
localhost/moduleName/controllerName/PageName/sort/price/desc/page/3
```

i would like to remove the /index/ too

My action Controller looks like this

```
    /**
     * Lists all models.
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('PageName',array(
            'pagination'=>array(
                'pageVar'=>'page'
            )
        ));
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }
```

My UrlManager looks like this

```
'PageName/page/<page:\d+>'=>'PageName/',
```

any idea who this can be done? or what i'm missing? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about getting to the url as you've specified. You can however get your url's in the following format in at least Yii 1.1 without adding additional rules to `urlManager`.

```
localhost/moduleName/controllerName/index/PageName_sort/price.desc/PageName_page/3
```

This is because `CController::createUrl()` is used to create the pagination links in [CPagination::createPageUrl()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination#createPageUrl-detail)

Comment: sorry, kind of a noob at this, so i have to override this function in a custom class, and how to i call it in CViewlist?  `public function createPageUrl($controller,$page)
{
    $params=$this->params===null ? $_GET : $this->params;
    if($page>0) // page 0 is the default
        $params[$this->pageVar]=$page+1;
    else
        unset($params[$this->pageVar]);
    return $controller->createUrl($this->route,$params);
}`